# Nested result sets as with dynamic names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to join the result of two referencing tables to get row values which are referencing different table names, which rows are selectable by their `uuid`.

my tables look like this:

table entry                  
table map
                     table cats
                           table dogs

<kbd>**nr**</kbd><kbd>**refInt**</kbd>
                   <kbd>**id**</kbd>  <kbd>**name**</kbd>                  <kbd>**mapRef**</kbd> <kbd>**breed**</kbd> 
                 
<kbd>**mapRef**</kbd>    <kbd>**breed**</kbd>    

 <kbd>1</kbd>   <kbd>123</kbd>                   
<kbd>123</kbd><kbd>'dogs'</kbd>
                
   <kbd>456</kbd>    <kbd>'bengal'</kbd>
                     <kbd>123</kbd>    <kbd>'sheepdog'</kbd> 
 <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>456</kbd>  
                 
<kbd>456</kbd> <kbd>'cats'</kbd>
                    <kbd>888</kbd>     <kbd>'birma'</kbd>                       <kbd>999</kbd>       <kbd>'poodle'</kbd>   

 <kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>789</kbd>  
                 
<kbd>789</kbd><kbd>'dogs'</kbd>
 <kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>123</kbd>

`refInt` of entry is referencing to map. the name of map is the reference to tables in addition with the field id which is also applied on the tables cats/dogs (dynamic tables loading).

```
// subset 1: list of numbers that needs to be loaded from entry table (1-4)
SELECT DISTINCT refInt FROM entry WHERE nr in (1,2,3,4)

// subset 2: get all names from map that have the same id like refInt from subset1
SELECT name FROM map WHERE id in subset1

// main query: load all rows from table with the given name
//             from map table that have the same mapRef value on it
SELECT * FROM (subset2.names) WHERE mapRef IN (subset2.ids)
```

result should be the rows:

```
1) 456 bengal
2) 123 sheepdog
```

I also made a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8bff1) of it.

Is there a way to combine this to one query?

Comment: You tagged this with sql-server but your fiddle is mysql and is using datatypes not available to sql -server. Which one is it?

Comment: Is there a typo in your first `SELECT`?  Should it actually be: `SELECT DISTINCT refInt FROM entry WHERE nr in (1,2,3,4)` ???

Comment: Why is the schema not [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)?  The map table shouldn't even exist.

Comment: @ Sean changed it - thanks
@ David yeah right, corrected it
@ Erik This is a simplified version of my database scheme. it is representing a tree structure with predefined types with dynamic fields linked to other tables.

Comment: based on your comment to @ErikPhilips answer, you're going to need to use dynamic sql to handle this.

Comment: @TabAlleman or a normalized database..

Comment: based on the data, your result rows should include `4) sheepdog`.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to look something like:

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/546ac/3)

```
select 
  sub.nr, 
  sub.breed
from (
    select e.nr, e.refInt, 
      case 
        when c.breed is not null then c.breed
        when d.breed is not null then d.breed
        else null
      end as breed
    from (
       select e.nr, e.refInt, m.name
       from entry e
       inner join map m on e.refInt = m.id
    ) e
    left join cats c on e.refInt = c.mapRef and e.name = 'cats'
    left join dogs d on e.refInt = d.mapref and e.name = 'dogs'
) sub
where sub.breed is not null
```

This is going to be very poor in performance.

Now the IMO the correct schema would be:

```
table entry
nr refint
1  123
2  456
3  789
4  124 (duplicate?)

table breed
mapRef breed    species
123    sheepdog 1
999    poodle   1
456    bengal   2 
888    birma    2

table species
id  species
1   dogs
2   cats
```

This is normalized and has very good performance.

Comment: Thanks, but the names of tables (cats/dogs) are not static - imagine there are 100 of them and the name column links to the right table.

Comment: yeah thats the problem, you don't have a good schema.  Storing the *Tablename* to look up a value in is not best practice, hard to do and can have the worst performance.

Comment: @kerosene, if possible, update schema as Erik suggested. If not, you may consider create a view that UNION ALL your dogs/cats tables with additional column tablename that you can join it normal way. However, performance would be poor that way

Comment: Okay thanks guys - I think you shouldn't judge if you don't know the scenario/use case. I can't change the schema. My alternative way would be to get all table names from table map and fire a second sql query.

Comment: Judging is a good thing.  When I go to work for a company I ask them to see some code. If that company is writing crappy code.. why would I work for them assuming they want me to write code like that...

Comment: but that's usually not what happening - business heads are making decisions about products

Comment: I also wouldn't want to work there.  Where I work now, the *Business Heads* request features and my team provides the *implemented solutions*.  Business heads shouldn't be making implementation decisions (doesn't mean it doesn't happen:(  ).

Comment: UNION ALL is better than OUTER JOIN for this circumstance. It both better reflects the underlying schema errors, and allows better performance when only a few rows are being selected from each partition.

Comment: There are two things that come up: a) there is already a implementation for a different product that uses this database schema b) I don't know if there is a better way to structure a case like that. I made a sketch if you're interested: http://i.imgur.com/OcEn2Ku.png (nodes->entry, categories->map)

Answer (score 1):

Note how the following query fully achieves the desired result set and fully demonstrates how the tables *cats* and *dogs* are truly just *partitions* of a single entity *animals*. The schema should be reworked to reflect this new understanding. This query is also efficient because the inclusion test id pushed to the depths of the innermost CTE's, at the level where actual table rows are being read, without relying on the engine to discover this potential optimization (which can be problematic with UNIONs).

```
with
cats2 as (
  select species='cat', mapref, breed
  from cats animals
  join entry on entry.refint = animals.mapref
  where entry.nr  in (1,2,3,4)
),
dogs2 as (
  select species='dog', mapref, breed
  from dogs animals
  join entry on entry.refint = animals.mapref
  where entry.nr  in (1,2,3,4)
),
animals as (
  select species, mapref, breed from cats2
  union all
  select species, mapref, breed from dogs2
)
select species, mapref, breed 
from animals
group by species, mapref, breed
```

This test script:

```
declare @entry table (nr int, refint int );
declare @map table (id int, name varchar(20) );
declare @cats table (mapRef int, breed varchar(20));
declare @dogs table (mapRef int, breed varchar(20));

insert @entry(nr,refint) values
     (1,123)
    ,(2,456)
    ,(3,789)
    ,(4,123);
insert @map(id,name) values
     (123,'dogs')
    ,(456,'cats')
    ,(789,'dogs');

insert @cats(mapRef,breed) values
    (456,'bengal'),(888,'burma');

insert @dogs(mapRef,breed) values
    (123,'sheepdog'), (999,'poodle');


with
cats2 as (
  select species='cat', mapref, breed
  from @cats animals
  join @entry entry on entry.refint = animals.mapref
  where entry.nr  in (1,2,3,4)
),
dogs2 as (
  select species='dog', mapref, breed
  from @dogs animals
  join @entry entry on entry.refint = animals.mapref
  where entry.nr  in (1,2,3,4)
),
animals as (
  select species, mapref, breed from cats2
  union all
  select species, mapref, breed from dogs2
)
select species, mapref, breed 
from animals
group by species, mapref, breed
```

yields as desired:

```
species mapref      breed
------- ----------- --------------------
cat     456         bengal
dog     123         sheepdog
```